# Using SIGAR API to calculate CPU usage

Tags: java, cpu, cpu-usage, sigar

I am using SIAGR API to calculate CPU usage but getting the exception when it is **tested with LOAD RUNNER** other wise it is ok.

```
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarFileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Cpu.gather(Native Method)
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Cpu.fetch(Cpu.java:30)
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getCpu(Sigar.java:320)
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getCpuPerc(Sigar.java:348)
```

please find sample code below

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Shell shell = new Shell();
        shell.setPageSize(PageControl.SIZE_UNLIMITED);

        Sigar sigar = shell.getSigar();

        CpuPerc cpu = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(500L);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            cpu = sigar.getCpuPerc();
            double val = cpu.getCombined();

            int cpuUsage = (int) (val * 100);
            // System.out.println(CpuPerc.format(val));
            System.out.println(cpuUsage);
        }
    } 
    catch (SigarException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My Requirement is to collect the CPU Usage at specific time interval for 50 cycles.. and log the average and highest.

Please help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not use the built-in capabilities of LoadRunner to connect to the native interfaces of Windows and LINUX/UNIX to collect the CPU data?   You appear to be re-engineering an already constructed and rolling wheel

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question or may be i have conveyed it wrongly..Here I have not written above code for load runner. My product needs to collect CPU usage at regular intervals not Loadrunner.Here my product is tested with load runner with some huge load.Here A background thread will be collecting CPU usage. When there is load i am getting above exception.

Comment: Yes, that does clarify.   Thank you